# Permanently and completely disable onscreen keyboard for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, accessibility

I just installed a fresh copy of the (currently) newest Ubuntu LTS. Because I did this on an Acer with Touchscreen capability, it decided I want an on-screen keyboard which I very much do NOT. It's constantly in the way and completely unnecessary.

I've been searching for days for a solution, but it's already off in the settings, I can't find any way to force remove it from the filesystem or otherwise make it behave. How do I deal with this nuisance? As is, there's no way the computer will work for what I need.

Answer (score 5):

I used block caribou: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/
Though this also required that I run these commands: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107848/although-gnome-shell-integration-extension-is-running-native-host-connector-is

Using the two together seems to have done the job. It's weird because it looks like a browser extension of some kind, but it works for the whole OS.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, after installing the extension and rebooting, I had to open gnome-tweaks and activate the extension.

Answer (score -1):

A temporary solution is to remove the virtual keyboard:

```
su ... dnf remove qt5-qtvirtualkeyboard.x86_64
```

However a system update will restore it, so it has to be manually removed again.

Comment: dnf? ...? May I please have a working example of this command?